# Why do I get poor performance when rendering different images with UIImage on iPhone

Tags: iphone, performance, uiimage, render

I'm using UIImage to render a game map from 32x32 blocks. The code is as follows

```
for( int x = 0; x < rwidth; ++x)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < rheight; ++y)
    {
        int bindex = [current_map GetTileIndex:x :y];
        CGPoint p;
        p.x = x * tile_size_x;
        p.y = y * tile_size_x;
        [img_list[bindex] drawAtPoint:p];
    }
}
```

This ends up rendering about 150 tiles. My problem is when I run this code my render time goes down to 2-3 frames a second.

I thought the iPhone was fill bound, however if I force bindex to = 1 (ie render the same block 150 times) then I get full framerate.

I can't believe it is that expensive to render from different UIImages.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong ...

Oh I forgot to mention my image list created from a bigger texture page using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect.

Thanks
Rich

Comment: Does each index in img_list reference a different texture/image loaded from separate files?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention my image list created from a bigger texture page using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect.

Comment: Sorry to answer your question, no.

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but how much work is your GetTileIndex function doing?

Comment: return map_index[map_width * y + x];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crack open Instruments and profile your code.  It looks like you are drawing into a UIView, and they are not really optimized for games..  Since UIViews are layer-backed, drawAtPoint: needs to draw the image several times (to offscreen buffers) before it appears on screen.

That being said, UIImage isn't really designed for games.  There's a lot of overhead with regards to being part of UIKit.  You're not really meant to have hundreds of them.

In approx order of speed (slowest to fastest):

- UIImage (usually used if you have a few large images)
- CALayers (if you need fine animation control or you have roughly 20 to 100 tiles/images)
- OpelGL textures (what most games should be using)

Comment: Thanks, I was going to go straight to opengl, however the docs kept persuading me that CGDrawImage was highly optmizied. As I only needed a tiled background I figured it was good enough ... guess not.